# How to combine two sliders on Altair chart?

Tags: pandas, slider, altair

I have the following DataFrame  :

```
   num_tra num_ts Year  Value
0      0    0      1     100
1      0    0      2     90
2      0    0      3     80
3      0    1      1     90
4      0    1      2     81
5      0    1      3     72
6      1    0      1     81
7      1    0      2     73
8      1    0      3     65
9      1    1      1     73
10     1    1      2     66
11     1    1      3     58
12     2    0      1     142
13     2    0      2     160
14     2    0      3     144
15     2    1      1     128
16     2    1      2     144
17     2    1      3     130
```

Based on the Multiple Interactions Altair example, I tried to build a chart with two sliders based (in this example) on values of columns num_tra [0 to 2] and num_ts [0 to 1] but it doesn't work

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

base = alt.Chart(df, width=500, height=300).mark_line(color="Red").encode(
    x=alt.X('Year:Q'),
    y='Value:Q',
    tooltip="Value:Q"
)

# Slider filter
tra_slider = alt.binding_range(min=0, max=2, step=1)
ts_slider = alt.binding_range(min=0, max=1, step=1)

slider1 = alt.selection_single(bind=tra_slider, fields=['num_tra'], name="TRA")
slider2 = alt.selection_single(bind=ts_slider, fields=['num_ts'], name="TS")

filter_TRA = base.add_selection(
    slider1,slider2
).transform_filter(
    slider1,slider2
).properties(title="Sensi_TRA")

filter_TRA
```

*=> TypeError: transform_filter() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given*

No problem with one slider but as mentioned, I wasn't able to combine two or more sliders on the same chart.

If you have any idea, it would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this. If you want the filters to be applied sequentially, you can use two transform statements:

```python
filter_TRA = base.add_selection(
    slider1,slider2
).transform_filter(
    slider1
).transform_filter(
    slider2
)
```

Alternatively, you can use a single transforms statement and use the `&` or `|` operators to filter on the intersection or union of the slider values, respectively:

```
filter_TRA = base.add_selection(
    slider1,slider2
).transform_filter(
    slider1 & slider2
)
```

Comment: Ok Perfect. That's exactly what I wanted.Thanks